# Unable to change button image in uitableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I am making a forum app similar to stack overflow. There is a UITableView displaying the answers to a question, and each cell (which contains an answer) also contains a 'correct answer' tick button. Only one answer can be selected as the correct answer at any given time. The correct answer is marked with a green tick, whilst the others are marked with a grey tick  (I have two identical images but with different colors). I am trying to set it so when the user clicks on a tick button that is grey, the currently green button turns grey, and the grey button that was tapped turns green.

```
@IBOutlet weak var answeredTick: UIButton!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell.answeredTick.tag = indexPath.row
}

@IBAction func answerTickPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let answeredTick = sender as? UIButton else { return }

    //indexOfOfficialAnswerId is the currently registered official ID
    if let buttonToMakeGrey = answeredTick.viewWithTag(self.indexOfOfficialAnswerId) as? UIButton {
        print("success!")
        buttonToMakeGrey.setImage(UIImage(named: "greyTick.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    } else {
        print("no success")
    }
}
```

However it always prints "no success". The value of indexOfOfficialAnswerId is correct during the if statement. I am able to make answerTicks that are grey turn green, but i cant make the green one grey. Why is this?

UPDATE: It appears that i can make the green tick grey if i click on the green tick, but not if i click on any of the grey ticks

Comment: btw you have to set other image in else block also

Comment: What do you mean? @iAnurag

Answer (score 0):

You can find cell with green tick as so:

```
NSIndexPath  *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.indexOfOfficialAnswerId inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

And then use your:

```
cell.answeredTick.setImage(UIImage(named: "greyTick.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Sorry for Objective-C code

Comment: No problem on the Obc-C, i converted it :) . I am not able to use this because the indexOfOfficialAnswerId is not stored within the cell. It is calculated and stored as a local variable

Comment: Am I correct that function answerTickPressed in cell class? Then you can add to cell delegate (to class, where tableView stored) and call its method in answerTickPressed. Where you would have above code.

Comment: what does it mean to be in a cell class?

Comment: As I understand, you have class that inherit UITableViewCell, where you have answeredTick property and answerTickPressed method. Or no?

Comment: Create in that cell class property "delegate" as something like id<CorrectAnswerProtocol>. In that protocol you would have one function, for example "correctAnswerWasChanged". You have class where your table view stored and cells created, for example I would call that class "A". "A" need adopt CorrectAnswerProtocol. Where you create cell, write cel.delegate = self (where self our class "A").  And finally call delegate.correctAnswerWasChanged in method "answerTickPressed"

Comment: No i have no fixed it. I am new to swift and i am struggling to understand your answer. But i appreciate your help

Comment: also, the code you posted causes an error "value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'answeredTick'"

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading that cell after setting that button image or changing its state as selected. I guess that might be the problem .